# Difference between 'tie ĉi' and 'ĉi tie'

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

I saw these two phrases in the sentences

```
"Ni loĝas tie ĉi."
```

and

```
"Kiom da homoj lernas Esperanton ĉi tie?"
```

Do 'tie ĉi' and 'ĉi tie' have precisely the same meaning and usage?

Otherwise, I guess 'tie ĉi' is used for a declarative sentence and 'ĉi tie' is used for an interrogative sentence.

Answer (score 3):

`tie ĉi` kaj `ĉi tie` havas ekzakte la saman signifon. Laŭ [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/lokaj/chi.html):

> Normale estas egale, ĉu oni metas ĉi antaŭ aŭ post la tabelvorto, sed iafoje la loko de ĉi estas grava. Oni prefere ne diru ekz. *tie ĉi tiu knabino loĝas*, ĉar estas malklare, ĉu ĉi apartenas al tie aŭ al tiu. Diru ekz. ĉi tie tiu knabino loĝas, aŭ tie tiu ĉi knabino loĝas, depende de la signifo.

En [kunmetaĵoj kun `ĉi`](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/lokaj/chi.html#i-h6f) oni metas `ĉi` komencen:

... por nia ĉitiea amiko?”

(*tieĉia* laŭ mi teorie eblas sed mi neniam aŭdis aŭ legis tiun formon kaj PMEG asertas: *"Ĉi ne povas ricevi finaĵojn."*)

Answer (score 1):

First notice that there are two *ĉi* words or word parts. The first one is the one in the correlatives, *tabelvortoj*, those *ĉiu, ĉio, ĉia…*. However these are not any combinations of some prefix *ĉi-* and some ending or such. These are indivisible words with the sence of "every, all" + body, thing, kind etc.

The second *ĉi* is a single word having three definitions (see [PIV](https://vortaro.net/#%C4%89i_kd)). They all express a sence of proximity. It is this sence you have in *ĉi tie* and *tie ĉi*. These two mean exactly the same with the caveat Eduardo already pointed out.

Why the two different versions? My guess is that some early Esperantists who spoke Romance languages natively equalled this *ĉi* with adjectives which are placed after its main word in those languages. This is the reason why you can say both *bela domo* and *domo bela*, although the latter way has fallen out fashion later. So they preferred *tie ĉi* over *ĉi tie*.

In [*Lingva respondo 104*](https://tekstaro.com/t?nomo=lingvaj-respondoj#lingvaj-respondoj-resp-104) Zamenhof gives permission to both ways, but makes a remark that for reasons of pronunciation putting *ĉi* before is to be preferred.

Note, in order to avoid confusion between these two *ĉi*, the latter, the one expressing proximity, should always be combined with a hyphen with non-correlatives. That is write *ĉi-tiea* instead of *ĉitiea* (see the LR104 above for an example by Z).

Comment: The reference to the Romance languages is interesting. In French _ci_ ("here") is used in _ceci_ (as opposed to _cela_)  and _celui-ci_ and such playing the same role as _ĉi_. I prefer `ĉi` as modifying adverb before the corellative. Note also _ĉiuj ĉi_ (more frequent I think) and _ĉi ĉiuj_.